# contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch) when use truffle console --network kovan

Tags: truffle, smart-contract-wallets, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment, kovan

i'm trying to call a function from contract that i deployed to kovan network, then when i used the truffle console --network kovan and tried to deploy my contract, it says that this contract has not been deployed to detected network but it's already deployed and even use it in my web3 app.

```
truffle(kovan)> const daiToken = await DaiToken.deployed()
Uncaught:
Error: DaiToken has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

My contract on etherscan kovan: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x478A24D4CcbFedE653D6aeE3DC202663e4ba2Be0

netowrk configuration at truffle-config.js:

```
 kovan: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, endpointUrl),
      network_id: 42,       
      gas: 5500000,        
      confirmations: 2, 
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      networkCheckTimeoutnetworkCheckTimeout: 10000,
      skipDryRun: true 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the token is already deployed.

Use  `await DaiToken.at(ADDRESS_HERE);` inside your code.
Where for `ADDRESS_HERE` substitute it with the contract address where DaiToken was deployed to on kovan.

For example in my code:

```
const Router = artifacts.require('uniswapv2/UniswapV2Router02.sol');
...
const router = await Router.at('0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'); // Kovan Uniswap V2 Router
```

This would get the `Router` instance that is deployed at that address

Comment: Yes, worked.. there is no way to deploy it again when i elready deployed it i just have to use its contract adress. thank's.